# Why is running 2 processes on 2 cores slower than on a single core?

Tags: php, python, cpu-usage

I would expect some overhead from context switching when running two processes on the same CPU core. What I didn't expect is so much overhead when running two processes on two separate CPU cores.

Here is my Python program to do some counting:

```python
import time

start = time.time()
j = 0

for i in range(0, 80000000):
    j += i

elapsed = time.time() - start
print("\nElapsed: %f" % elapsed)
```

By itself this program completes in about 7 seconds. If I run this program twice simultaneously on the same CPU core:

```
$ taskset --cpu-list 0 time python3 cpu-bound.py & taskset --cpu-list 0 time python3 cpu-bound.py &

Elapsed: 15.553317
7.77user 0.01system 0:15.59elapsed 49%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 8924maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+942minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Elapsed: 15.840124
8.10user 0.00system 0:15.90elapsed 50%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 9060maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+946minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I get 14-15 seconds, which is expected as they run on the same CPU, so one has to be paused for the other one to run, etc. However, running the two processes on different CPU cores:

```
$ taskset --cpu-list 0 time python3 cpu-bound.py & taskset --cpu-list 1 time python3 cpu-bound.py &

Elapsed: 17.081092
17.10user 0.00system 0:17.12elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 8848maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+943minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Elapsed: 17.094898
17.10user 0.00system 0:17.14elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 8948maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+944minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I would expect each process to report a time that's close to the original 7 seconds, because the processes are running in parallel and on separate cores.

However, I'm seeing 15-17 seconds execution on each process.

Could anyone please shed some light on this behavior? Thank you!

**Update**: I'll describe the environments I tried to run this in below.

First I ran this in a Docker container on an M1 Mac which has 4 cores. CPU 0 and 1 are the first and second core respectively. I then ran again on a t3.medium VM on AWS which has 2 vCPUs and observed similar results.

**Update**: I also got similar results in PHP, as well a php-fpm static pool with 1 worker (to run sequentially), with 2 workers with CPU affinity (to run in parallel on a single core) and with 2 workers without affinity (parallel on two cores). I observed the similar behavior -- running in parallel on separate cores is nowhere near as fast as an original single run.

I then decided to try a similar program in C and the results were very different and very much in line with what I expected in the first place:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
    
int main() {
    time_t t;
    double elapsed;
    int i, j = 0;
    t = time(NULL);
    
    for (i = 0; i <= 2000000000; i++) {
        j += i;
    }
    
    t = time(NULL) - t;
    elapsed = ((double) t);
    printf("Elapsed: %f\n", elapsed);
    return 0;
}
```

A single run was about 6 seconds (time_t is rounded to seconds):

```
$ ./a.out 
Elapsed: 6.000000
```

Two runs on a single CPU core yielded:

```
$ taskset --cpu-list 0 ./a.out & taskset --cpu-list 0 ./a.out &
Elapsed: 12.00
Elapsed: 12.00
```

Two runs on separate CPU cores gave:

```
$ taskset --cpu-list 0 ./a.out & taskset --cpu-list 1 ./a.out &
Elapsed: 6.00
Elapsed: 6.00
```

This behavior is more in line with what I expected in the first place, but why is it so drastically different for Python and PHP?

Comment: Could you describe the environment where this was run? Specifically, what is the relation between "cpu 0" and  "cpu 1"?  Different cores? Different threads on the same core?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist updated the question to add more context and some other observations. Thanks!

Comment: Points of reference from what I think is a more straightforward environment: Python version: same core: 7.457889 / 7.713524, different cores: 3.700021 / 3.870121, C version: same core 2.000000/2.000000 / different cores:  1.000000/1.000000.

Comment: Regarding the AWS t3.medium test you did, that is a 2 threads 1 core environment afaik(?). The Docker on Mac environment intuitively just feels complicated in terms of knowing what to expect when faced with strange results. I at least don't know exactly what to expect without starting to research what that setup is; fundamentally I *assume* it's just a Linux VM with some number of cores assigned to it, at least as long as the container is also arm64 (as your M1 host), if it's some cross-arch setup I guess there is more to it...

Answer (score 1):

> This behavior is more in line with what I expected in the first place,
> but why is it so drastically different for Python and PHP?

Both Python and PHP are high-level, interpreted languages. You can't really know what the interpreter is doing with your code.

> I then decided to try a similar program in C and the results were very
> different and very much in line with what I expected in the first place

Which is one of the main reasons why C is used.

> First I ran this in a Docker container on an M1 Mac which has 4 cores.
> CPU 0 and 1 are the first and second core respectively. I then ran
> again on a t3.medium VM on AWS which has 2 vCPUs and observed similar
> results.

Also, please note that running such tests in virtual machines or containers doesn't really make much sense.